# How to import a python script without a .py extension?

Tags: python

I have this doubt, how can I import a file, `test.cookie`, ending with the `.cookie` extension for example, instead of the `.py`

```
import test.cookie
```

Like that, of course, that doesn't work, but, do you have an idea? Please give it to me with example

In the case using with for read the file, how can I execute the text it is inside the file?

Comment: Yess, that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader 

spec = spec_from_loader("test", SourceFileLoader("test", "/path/to/test.cookie"))
test = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(test)
```

Comment: And, do you know how to run it?

Comment: I mean like, in the case test.cookie have print("Hi") so, how can I run it?

Comment: It is with exec but, how can I access to it in case it is a json file

Comment: My initial answer was wrong, I did some more research and it should be correct now. This lets you load a module with any kind of filename.

Comment: OHH, it worked! I saw a post like this in searching but it didnt work, I forgot to put one directory xD, thank you very much!!